# How to make matplotlib contour lines with edgecolors?

Tags: matplotlib, contour

I would like to add edgecolors to the lines in matplolib.pyplot.contour. Tried edgecolors and markeredgecolors, without effect. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Do you mean you want the different contours (which are lines) in different colors?

Comment: No, I want e.g. red lines with white edgecolors, because the background is redish. A specific usecase requires it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a case such as this, you'll want to plot the dataset *twice*, the first time with a thicker linewidth (or larger markers, depending on what type of plot you had in mind) and in the color of the "outer" lines/markers. Then, you plot the dataset again, but with smaller lines/markers and in a different color, the color of the inner line.

Here's an example that you can copy-paste to study. The example borrows from the [matplotlib contour demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some sample data
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

plt.figure()
# plot the outer lines thicker
whites = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors='white', linewidths=7)
plt.gca().set_axis_bgcolor('red')  # you spoke of a red bgcolor in the axis (yuck!)
# and plot the inner lines thinner
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors='red', linewidths=3)
```

This is a commonly used technique in many decent graphs, to highlight the data (even though this example looks awful).